# Calculation of limit with different root indexes

Tags: calculus, limits, roots

maybe you can help me to find a limit of a function with different root indexes? This type of roots is pretty hard for me and I want to know the pattern how to solve exercises like this. Thanks!

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{1/3} - 2x^{3/2}} {x^{4/5} + x^{3/2}} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't feel comfortable with roots, get rid of them.

For $x>0$,
$$
\frac{x^{1/3} - 2x^{3/2}} {x^{4/5} + x^{3/2}}
= \frac{x^{10/30} - 2x^{45/30}} {x^{24/30} + x^{45/30}}
$$
Now, setting $y=x^{1/30}$, we have $\lim_{x\to\infty} y = \infty$, so that when we substitute we get
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{10/30} - 2x^{45/30}} {x^{24/30} + x^{45/30}}
=
\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y^{10} - 2y^{45}} {y^{24} + y^{45}}
$$
Do you know how to figure out this last one?

**Detailed solution:**

> factor both numerator and denominator by the largest term, i.e., $y^{45}$.$$\frac{y^{10} - 2y^{45}} {y^{24} + y^{45}} =\frac{ - 2 + y^{-35}} {1+y^{-21}} \xrightarrow[y\to\infty]{}\frac{-2+0}{1+0}$$

Comment: Thanks! Hope that helps me a lot!

Comment: @Deividito You're welcome!

Comment: But what should I do if I don't have the same things under a root. For instance, in numerator i have $$x^2+1$$ and in denominator I have $$x^4+1$$ ?

Comment: Then do the same. $\frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1} = \frac{1/x^2+1/x^4}{1+1/x^4} \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} \frac{0+0}{1+0}$

Comment: For instance: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(x^2+1)^{1/2} - (x^2+1)^{1/3}} {2(x^4+1)^{1/4} + (x^4+1)^{1/5}} $$

Comment: So i should take "y" anymore?

Comment: It's different, but then do something similar. For $x>0$, $(x^2+1)^{1/2} + (x^2+1)^{1/3} = x(1+1/x^2)^{1/2} + x^{2/3}(1+1/x^3)^{1/3}$.

Comment: Thanks one more time... My hero <3